# MANOVA or multiple regression, multivariate regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, manova, psychology

I am looking at the association between feature [ vividness, content specificity, and content narrative] - to three variables on the levels of Depression ( 4 levels - normal, mild, severe, and very severe).  What sort of test do I run here?  Multiple regression? Multivariate Regression a MANOVA.

Comment: So you have `depression` (ordered factor) as response and `vividness`, `content specificity`, `content narrative` as explanatory variables? Is this right?

Comment: @utobi I think that’s what she meant yes. Catarina, why not just compute a covariance matrix, and then normalize it to compute a matrix of Pearson correlation coefficients?